# Related field invalid lookup error even though everything has been written right

Tags: python

While I was adding a search bar I encountered a Invalid Lookup error even though I have
"icontains". I hope someone can help me. If anything else is needed please do ask.

Traceback:

```
FieldError at /search_posts
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

search_posts.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    
    {% if searched %}
        <h1>Search Results For {{ searched }}</h1>
        <br/>
        {% for posts in post %}
            {{ post }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
        <h1>Hey!! You Did Not Search For Anything.</h1>

    {% endif %}
    

    <br/><br/>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def search_posts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        post = Post.objects.filter(author__icontains=searched)


        return render(request, 'search_posts.html',{'searched':searched, 'post':post})

    else:

        return render(request, 'search_posts.html',{})
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='intro')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('article-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
        return reverse('home')
```

Comment: Is `author` a field that represents a relationship or is it a concrete `CharField()` in your model? Pls provide your model. If `author` is a `ForeignKey()`-field you must span a filter over your models, e.g. `.filter(author__name__icontains=searched)`

Comment: @KlimBim Yep I have provided models for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the failure says. It seems to be that `author` is a `ForeignKey()`-field and you have a relationship between `User` and `Post`.

You must span a filter over your models.

`post = Post.objects.filter(author__username__icontains=searched)`

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/) you can find fields of the `User`-model

##### update

and change
`author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

to

`author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

[settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Comment: @Kaushik I updated `name` to `username`. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Why do I have to change my authors thing though and it works. thx But I don't understand why I need to change that. Also I keep on getting something like this:"<QuerySet [<Post: Goals | Kaushik>]>" While I only want Goals to appear.

Comment: @Kaushik added a link to django doc

Comment: @Kaushik Because a `.filter` always returns a queryset (filter returns multiple matches). If you are sure that the database returns only one instance you can use `.get()`